# How to make a variable for each line of a txt file in python

Tags: python, line, edit

I think this question was already asked but I can't find it so I'm going to ask it. I want to be able to open a .txt file and make each line in to a variable.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by *"make each line in to a variable"*? What do you want to happen? What have you tried? And what happened instead?

Comment: Okay. So what I mean is I want to open a txt file. Take the first line and save it as the variable named 'username'. I then want it to loop something then go to the next line and make the variable 'username' the next line.

Comment: Instead of overwriting your variable each time it would be better to use @KeeganKuhn 's linked solution and work with a list of usernames.

Comment: Okay. I think I found what I wanted here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list

Comment: You just need to do your for loop for each username in the list after that procedure.